# Lagrange multipler and heat flow

Tags: calculus

> A heated storage room is shaped like a rectangular box and has the
> volume of 1000 cubic feet. As the hot air rises, the heat loss per
> unit of ´area through the roof is five times greater than the heat
> loss from the floor. The heat loss through the four walls is three
> times greater than the heat loss through the floor. Determine the
> dimensions of the room that minimizes heat loss and therefore
> minimizes the cost of heating.

I am a little confused in how to solve it, i mean:

H is the height

L is the width

C is the length.

$$\phi_{r} = 5 \phi_{f}$$
$$2 \phi_{WallA}/HL + 2 \phi_{WallB}/HC = 3 \phi_{f}/CL$$

We want to minimize $\phi = \phi_{r} + \phi_{f} + 2 \phi_{WallA} + 2 \phi_{WallB}$

Subject to $$V = HLC$$

Now the standard approach would be to use Lagrange multipliers, but as we apply it, we note that it will give wrong answers, so i think my equations showed above is wrong. What is the problem?

Comment: Your heat flux density (heat loss) is per unit area, so you want to multiply by the rectangular areas, not divide by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify the notation, I'll make $(C,L,H)=(x,y,z)$, and work with units such that the heat loss per unit of area through the floor is $1$. I'll also assume that the sentence "The heat loss through the four walls is three times greater than the heat loss through the floor" refers to the heat loss per unit of area. With this assumption, the total heat loss is given by
\begin{align*}
F&=1\times(\mathrm{area\, of\, the\, floor})+5\times(\mathrm{area\, of\, the\, ceiling})+3\times (\mathrm{area\,of\,the\,walls}) \\
&= xy+5xy+3(2xz+2yz) \\
&= 6(xy+yz+zx),
\end{align*}
which must be minimized subject to the constraint that $V=xyz=1000$. To solve this problem, we use the method of Lagrange multipliers, and look for the critical points of
\begin{align*}
G&=F-\lambda(V-1000) \\
&=6(xy+yz+zx)-\lambda(xyz-1000).
\end{align*}
Differentiating $G$ with respect to $x,y,z$ and $\lambda$ and equating the results to zero we obtain the following system of equations:
\begin{align*}
&6(y+z)-\lambda yz = 0, \\
&6(z+x)-\lambda zx = 0, \\
&6(x+y)-\lambda xy = 0, \\
&xyz = 1000.
\end{align*}
Subtracting the second equation from the first, we obtain
$$
6(y-x)-\lambda z(y-x)=0\Longrightarrow (6-\lambda z)(y-x)=0\Longrightarrow
z=\frac{6}{\lambda}\quad \mathrm{or}\quad x=y.
$$
Inserting $z=6/\lambda$ in the first equation yields
$$
6\left(y+\frac{6}{\lambda}\right)-\lambda y\cdot\frac{6}{\lambda}=0\Longrightarrow 
\frac{36}{\lambda}=0,
$$
which has no solution. This leaves us with the other possibility, $x=y$. The third equation of the system then becomes
$$
12x-\lambda x^2=0\Longrightarrow x=0 \quad \mathrm{or}\quad x=\frac{12}{\lambda}.
$$
The solution $x=0$ can be discarded, as it would imply $V=0$. Inserting the second solution in the second equation of the system yields
$$
6\left(z+\frac{12}{\lambda}\right)-\lambda z\cdot\frac{12}{\lambda}=0\Longrightarrow 
\frac{72}{\lambda}-6z=0\Longrightarrow z=\frac{12}{\lambda},
$$
i.e., $z=x=y$. The last equation of the system then yields $\boxed{x=y=z=10}$.